# How to remove appended string from Cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I have strings that are appended to my cookie and when the user clicks a button I need the string that was clicked to be removed from the cookie. But the strings within the cookie that already exist need to remain there.

The functions are called through other API calls.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function(){
            document.getElementById('connStrings').innerHTML = "initialString";
            getProvidersForDisplay();
        }   

        function saveStringsState(stringsFromEvent)
        {
                var stringConns = stringsFromEvent.getConns;
                var div = document.getElementById('stringsConnected');
                div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + " " + stringConns;

                Cookies.set('connStrings', div.innerHTML);  
        }

        function removeStringPassed(removedString)
        {
            var removedConnection = eventObj.provider;
            var div = document.getElementById('stringsConnected');

            div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML - removedString;
        }

        function getProvidersForDisplay() {
                if((Cookies.get('connStrings') != null)) {
                    document.getElementById('stringsConnected').innerHTML = (Cookies.get('connStrings'));
                }
}
    </script>   
</head>
<body>
    <div id="strings">
    <p>Your strings are: <span id="stringsConnected"></span></p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The removeStringsPassed currently removes the string that was passed but lshows the initial string as NaN as its not a number and I'm doing a minus. Also its not being removed from the cookie so the actual strings that were set end up being in the same state.

Can someone please help me with this? Just to remove the removedString passed in from the current strings and from the cookie?

The cookie i am using is from here:https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie

Thanks

Edit:

I've added a split string to the innerHTML which seems to have done it, then setting the cookie. But now replaces it with a comma :/

**Edit**: 
Within the removeStringPassed i've used this :

```
div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML.split(removedString);
div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML.join("");
Cookies.set('provider', div.innerHTML);
```

But this replaces the string with commas, how can I stop this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this in the end and it worked fine:

Edit:

I've added a split string to the innerHTML which seems to have done it, then setting the cookie. But now replaces it with a comma :/

Edit: Within the removeStringPassed i've used this :

```
div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML.split(removedString);
div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML.join("");
Cookies.set('provider', div.innerHTML);
```

But this replaces the string with commas, how can I stop this?

```
div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML.split(removedString).join("");
```